# Non-blocking read takes ~100ms

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking

I'm using JAVA NIO with `SocketChannel` as follows:

```
   while (true) {
        int readyOperations = selector.select();
        if (readyOperations == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = it.next();

            if (key.isReadable()) {
                handleRead(key);
            }
            [...]
```

Then, inside `handleRead` I have this piece of code:

```
public void handleRead(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    ByteBuffer buf = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();

    long nanoStart = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("is channel blocking?: " + channel.isBlocking());
    int bytesRead = channel.read(buf);
    long nanoEnd = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("elapsed time (ms): " + (nanoEnd - nanoStart) / 1000_000.0);
```

and although I'm using non-blocking channels, the first time that `handleRead` is called I get big elapsed time. For instance:

```
is channel blocking?: false
elapsed time (ms): 123
```

After the first `handleRead` call, I get smaller values (< 0.5ms) for `elapsed time (ms)` that seem reasonable. However, still, once in a while I could see times in the range of ~10ms.

This does not seem to make sense since the channels I'm using are non-blocking. Why would it take more than 1ms to read data? Would the elapsed time be related to the amount of data that are read at a point in time? But, even then, I would expect that reading ~1000bytes at once will be less costly than <1ms. The `ByteBuffers` I use are `allocateDirect`ed.

Comment: Are you really measuring the `System.out` call too? Consider that the call to `println()` is `synchronized`.

Comment: Oops yes. But even without the `println()` the first time I see values in the range of ~10ms to ~20ms.

Comment: I'd expect that to be due to some initial overhead with socket I/O and/or platform config, not related to how much data you're reading.